# How to instantiate objects by using a list of object names

Tags: python

I'm trying to figure out how to initialize a number of objects from a string of name attributes. Each object is going to be mapped to a dictionary key. Here's the basic idea:

```
class Triangle(Shape):
    def __init__():
        Shape.__init__()
    name = "Triangle"

class Square(Shape):
    def __init__():
        Shape.__init__()
    name = "Square"

classTuple = (Triangle, Square)
classList = ["Triangle", "Square"]
classDict = {}

def initObjects():
    for shape in classList:
        for obj in classTuple:
            if obj.name == shape:
                classDict[shape] = obj(obj.sides, obj.corners #etc)

initObjects():
```

The only issue, however, is that the variables inside of classTuple are undefined and need to be set to the class objects. How would one go about doing that?

Answer (score 0):

Your `__init__()` methods are missing the `self` argument. Also I recommend to use the `super()` method.

```
class Triangle(Shape):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
    name = "Triangle"

class Square(Shape):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
    name = "Square"

classTuple = (Triangle, Square)
classList = ["Triangle", "Square"]
classDict = {}

def initObjects():
    for shape in classList:
        for obj in classTuple:
            if obj.name == shape:
                classDict[shape] = obj(obj.sides, obj.corners #etc)

initObjects()
```